# Standalone Spark - How to find final status (Driver's) for an application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I am setting up Spark 2.2.0 in standalone mode (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) and submitting spark jobs programatically using

```
SparkLauncher sparkAppLauncher = new SparkLauncher(userNameMap).setMaster(sparkMaster).setAppName(appName).....;
 SparkAppHandle sparkAppHandle = sparkAppLauncher.startApplication();
```

I do have java client program that polls Job status for the jobs submitted programatically, for which i am using following REST endpoint.
 curl  http://192.168.1.139:8080/json/ which provide JSON response as following,

```
{
  "url" : "spark://192.168.1.139:7077",
  "workers" : [ { "id" : "x", "host" : "x", "port" : x, "webuiaddress" : "x",
                  "cores" : x,  "coresused" : x, "coresfree" : x,  "memory" : xx,
                  "memoryused" : xx,  "memoryfree" : xx,  "state" : "x", "lastheartbeat" : x
                }, { ...},  ],
  "cores" : x,
  "coresused" : x,
  "memory" : x,
  "memoryused" : x,
  "activeapps" : [ ],
  "completedapps" : [ { "starttime" : x, "id" : "app-xx-xxxx", "name" : "abc", "user" : "xx",
                         "memoryperslave" : x, "submitdate" : "x","state" : "FINISHED OR RUNNING", "duration" : x
                      }, {...}],
  "activedrivers" : [ ],
  "status" : "x"
}
```

In above response, I have observed **state for completedapps is always FINISHED even if application fails**, while on UI (http://master:8080), associated driver shows a failed state, as captured below.

**Completed Applications**

```
Application ID - app-20190925115750-0003
Name - EXPORT_TABLE%1707        
Cores -     
Memory per Executor
Submitted Time
User
State - FINISHED
Duration
```

**Completed Drivers**

```
Submission ID - driver-20190925115748-0003
Submitted Time- 
Worker        - worker-20190925112049-192.168.1.110-46224
State         - FAILED
Cores
Memory
```

Referring to above example, Currently, My java client gets status  for application (app-20190925115750-0003) FINISHED, even though it got failed (encountered exception) and associated driver shows "FAILED" state. **I intend to show the final status in this case as FAILED**.

It seems if i can co-relate, an application-id (app-20190925115750-0003) to driver-id (driver-20190925115748-0003), I can report a "FAILED" (final) status. I could not find any co-relation between them (appID --> driver ID).

Looking forward to your suggestions to resolving this or any possible approaches to achieve this.
I have also come across some hidden REST APIs like http://xx.xx.xx.xx:6066/v1/submissions/status/driver-20190925115748-0003, which seems have a limited info returned in response.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api

Comment: This is based on history server, I intend to achieve this without the use of history server.

Comment: Hi Nilkanth Patel, Where you able to solve this issue?